# Hibernate não retorna dados

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para aprender, e ao tentar acessar a aplicação (JSF) o Hibernate não retorna dados. Tem alguma ideia?

Segue minha classe `Filter`:

```
package br.com.importacao.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;



/***
 * ESSE FILTER VAI SER CHAMADO TODA VEZ QUE FOR REALIZADO 
 * UMA REQUISIÇÃO PARA O FACES SERVLET.
 * */


@WebFilter(servletNames = {"Faces Servlet"})
public class JPAFilter implements Filter{

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private String persistence_unit_name = "unit_app";

    public  JPAFilter() {

    }

    public void destroy() {
        this.entityManagerFactory.close();
    } 

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


        //CRIANDO UM ENTITYMANAGER
        EntityManager entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        //ADICIONANDO ELE NA REQUISIÇÃO
        req.setAttribute("entityManager", entityManager);

        //INICIANDO UMA TRANSAÇÃO
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        //INICIANDO FACES SERVLET
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);

        try {
            //SE NÃO TIVER ERRO NA OPERAÇÃO ELE EXECUTA O COMMIT
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //SE TIVER ERRO NA OPERAÇÃO É EXECUTADO O rollback
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {

            entityManager.close();

        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

        //CRIA O entityManagerFactory COM OS PARÂMETROS DEFINIDOS NO persistence.xml
        this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(this.persistence_unit_name);

    }

}
```

Classe Autenticação:

```
package br.com.importacao.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import br.com.importacao.model.UsuarioModel;

@WebFilter("/sistema/*")
public class AutenticacaoFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {     
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession         httpSession         = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
        HttpServletRequest  httpServletRequest  =(HttpServletRequest)  request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse =(HttpServletResponse) response;

        if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().indexOf("index.xhtml") <= -1) {

            UsuarioModel usuarioModel = (UsuarioModel) httpSession.getAttribute("Usuário Autenticado");
            if (usuarioModel == null) {
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest.getContextPath()+ "/index.xhtml");
            } 
            else {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
        else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {        
    }

}
```

Arquivo de persistência:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="unit_app" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>
            ARQUIVO DE PERSISTÊNCIA JPA E HIBERNATE            
        </description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQL2014:1433;dataBaseName=Aplicacao" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sql2014" />


            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

E o log após tentar logar na aplicação:

> INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: unit_app
>     ...] set 10, 2018 11:58:14 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.0.Final} set 10, 2018 11:58:14 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found set 10, 2018 11:58:14 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist set 10, 2018 11:58:16 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.4.Final} set 10, 2018 11:58:16 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) set 10, 2018 11:58:16 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH000401: using driver
>   [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL
>   [jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQL2014:1433;dataBaseName=Aplicacao] set
>   10, 2018 11:58:16 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sa,
>   password=****} set 10, 2018 11:58:16 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false set 10, 2018
>   11:58:16 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
>   set 10, 2018 11:58:27 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO:
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect set
>   10, 2018 11:58:30 PM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  INFO:
>   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory set 10, 2018 11:58:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000228:
>   Running hbm2ddl schema update set 10, 2018 11:58:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000102:
>   Fetching database metadata set 10, 2018 11:58:37 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000396:
>   Updating schema set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000261: Table
>   found: Aplicacao.dbo.tbPessoa set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000037:
>   Columns: [id_usuario_cadastro, id_pessoa, id_usuario, fl_sexo,
>   nm_pessoa, dt_cadastro, ds_email, fl_origemcadastro, ds_endereco] set
>   10, 2018 11:58:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata 
>   INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_tbusuario_idusuario,
>   fk_6f0fndvdml1p57xaedm3x9hn] set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000126:
>   Indexes: [pk_tbpessoa_idpessoa] set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000261: Table
>   found: Aplicacao.dbo.tbUsuario set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000037:
>   Columns: [id_usuario, ds_senha, ds_login] set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000108:
>   Foreign keys: [] set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  INFO: HHH000126:
>   Indexes: [pk_tbusuario_idusuario] set 10, 2018 11:58:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000232:
>   Schema update complete set 10, 2018 11:58:47 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Deploying web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\docs set 10, 2018 11:58:52 PM
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES: At least
>   one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug
>   logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
>   but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 10, 2018
>   11:58:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\docs has finished in 5,451 ms
>   set 10, 2018 11:58:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\examples set 10, 2018 11:59:05
>   PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES: At least
>   one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug
>   logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
>   but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 10, 2018
>   11:59:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: contextInitialized() set 10, 2018
>   11:59:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: SessionListener: contextInitialized() set 10, 2018
>   11:59:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker',
>   'async.Stockticker@1d0af75') set 10, 2018 11:59:05 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Deployment of web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\examples has finished in
>   12,551 ms set 10, 2018 11:59:05 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Deploying web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\host-manager set 10, 2018
>   11:59:10 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES:
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 10,
>   2018 11:59:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\host-manager has finished in
>   4,901 ms set 10, 2018 11:59:10 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Deploying web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\manager set 10, 2018 11:59:18
>   PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES: At least
>   one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug
>   logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
>   but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 10, 2018
>   11:59:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\manager has finished in 8,092
>   ms set 10, 2018 11:59:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDirectory INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\ROOT set 10, 2018 11:59:24 PM
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFORMAÇÕES: At least
>   one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug
>   logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
>   but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. set 10, 2018
>   11:59:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory
>   C:\Servers\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\webapps\ROOT has finished in 5,672 ms
>   set 10, 2018 11:59:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>   INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] set 10, 2018
>   11:59:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFORMAÇÕES:
>   Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] set 10, 2018 11:59:24 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup
>   in 119273 ms

Hibernate:

```
    select
        usuarioent0_.id_usuario as id_usuar1_1_,
        usuarioent0_.ds_senha as ds_senha2_1_,
        usuarioent0_.ds_login as ds_login3_1_ 
    from
        tbUsuario usuarioent0_ 
    where
        usuarioent0_.ds_login=? 
        and usuarioent0_.ds_senha=?
```

Comment: Coloca sua página JSF também

Comment: Consegui resolver. Mas obrigado.

Comment: @Pereira compartilhe a solução conosco :). Você pode responder sua própria pergunta

Comment: O problema estava na definição:                                                          UsuarioModel usuarioModel = (UsuarioModel) httpSession.getAttribute("Usuário Autenticado");                                                                     o correto era UsuarioModel usuarioModel = (UsuarioModel) httpSession.getAttribute("usuarioAutenticado");

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, estava na definição:

```
UsuarioModel usuarioModel = (UsuarioModel) httpSession.getAttribute("Usuário Autenticado");
```

O correto era:

```
UsuarioModel usuarioModel = (UsuarioModel) httpSession.getAttribute("usuarioAutenticado");
```